# java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after connection closed . DB: mysql

Tags: java, mysql, c3p0

> Exception   :
>   java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

I got this strange exception when I tried to run my application. I am using local variable for connection object and after execution of some statements this exception is raising. I am using c3p0 connection pool and MySQL database.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is really hard to tell what exactly is wrong. Most likely you are performing operations on a `Statement` or `ResultSet` after you've closed the database connection.

Comment: I cannot show the code because it's very huge and i am not able to find what the exact issue is..i just wanted to know why this exception is arising.               
thanks in advance.

Comment: It's arising because you are executing a statement, or iterating over a `ResultSet`, after you have called `close()` on the database connection that the statement or `ResultSet` are associated with. Don't close the connection before you've executed the statement or iterated through the result. The stack trace will tell you where in your code you are performing an operation at the wrong moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to diagnose this without seeing your code, but I once had an similar problem due to the fact that mysql closes the connections after a while; so make sure that the configuration of your datasource has a validation query, and testOnBorrow and testWhileIdle are both true.

Here is an example:

```
    <Resource auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" name="jdbc/mydb"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://myserver/mydb"
            maxActive="10"
            maxIdle="5"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="10000"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
            username="???" password="???"/>
```